# What algorithm is appropriate for finding possible matches to form a group of L players?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Given a group of M1, M2, ... , Mn teams (each team has length <= L/2) I am trying to find (as efficiently as possible, iteratively) combinations which match the criteria:

- Total lobby size is L
- Each lobby is comprised of 2 sides (L/2 players)

Note:

- The teams on each side can be of different sizes. So this is perfectly valid for L=8 (thus each side = L/2 = 4): [A]+[B,C]+[D] vs [E,F,G]+[H]

Any pointers, links, hints appreciated.

Comment: "all possible combinations" - that sounds expensive.

Comment: @Dai Agreed. I have edited to indicate I can work with a stream of results as well.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it is not a good fit given the additional note above.

Comment: You can probably solve this using max flow

Comment: @juvian could u expand on what you said?

Comment: Is L the sum of all team lengths?

Comment: L is the total lobby size.